# I keep getting a Whitelabel Error Page when running Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, gradle

So I was trying to start up a RESTful Web Service and I was following the tutorial at their main page https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch. Everything was going well until I went to my terminal and ran `gradle bootRun` and when I went to http://localhost:8080/greeting nothing runs. Instead, I get a Whitelabel Error Page instead of getting Hello, World!. I even watched a video on youtube but it seems everyone I watch is using Maven instead of Gradle. Anywho here are my files. I can't seem to figure this out. The application boots but it just doesn't show up on the actual site.

**Greeting.java**

```
public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I would really appreciate any help in advance. If you need me to post anything else or be more specific please do say so. Im a beginner at this stuff as it is a project for my school. I figured this would be the best place to ask.

Edit 1: This is what shows up on the console on my terminal where I am running the application.

```
2021-02-22 14:47:01.527  INFO 12332 --- [           main] c.e.p.ProjectPolandApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default2021-02-22 14:47:02.118  INFO 12332 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-02-22 14:47:02.130  INFO 12332 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-02-22 14:47:02.130  INFO 12332 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2021-02-22 14:47:02.182  INFO 12332 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-02-22 14:47:02.182  INFO 12332 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 626 ms  
2021-02-22 14:47:02.288  INFO 12332 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-22 14:47:02.374  INFO 12332 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''     
2021-02-22 14:47:02.380  INFO 12332 --- [           main] c.e.p.ProjectPolandApplication           : Started ProjectPolandApplication in 1.14 seconds (JVM running for 1.402)
```

Edit 2: My directory looks like the following

`src/main/java/com/example/projectpoland/`

I have all of my files in the same folder.

[Directory and File Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjAe1.png)

Edit 3: I'm not sure if this is relevant but this is what my Application.java looks like

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProjectPolandApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectPolandApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the error page (as text, not as image)? Is there anything in the console? Do you use packages? If so, can you show your directory structure?

Comment: Do you use packages? Is your main class in the same package or in a package above your controller.

Comment: When I said console, I meant the console where you ran the application and not the browser console. But in case of a 404, it is not really important.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because you are hitting https, when your actual service doesn't support https.
Try changing the request URL to http://localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: Well Im actually using the site from the tutorial which is http://localhost:8080/greeting. I wrote https by accident.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually figured it out. Turns out I was setting my package for Greeting.java and GreetingController.java to main.java.com.example.projectpoland instead of leaving it as it was because my IDE suggested changing it. Thank you for your help everyone.